# How to combining the files in queue using filename?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have process two files(file1 and file2) and result of processing 2 files is 1000 flow files which is queued.

Now i need to combine flow files using **"filename"** attribute.

**For example:** 1000 flow files in queues(unordered).we need to combine flow files if filename is file1/file2. And then process it based on FIFO strategy.

combine all flow files based on it's filename.

is it possible in NiFi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your use case, but check out the [MergeContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html) processor, you could set "filename" for the Correlation Attribute Name property, that should combine together all flow files that have the same filename.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [RouteOnAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnAttribute/) processor?
From what you describe it feels that this might do the job.
[image]

Comment: mrjosph,I should n't give filename to split it.Any generic way to check filename?

Comment: ${filename} returns the actual filename, the exact rule you provide in Value column above depends on your needs (it might be even a regular expression). If you have only two files, you can provide a matching rule only for one (this would go to "matched"), the other one would go to "unmatched" flow.